# Php image validation

Tags: php, image

Thus anyone has any idea why this code is not working for me

```
$type1 = $_FILES['textfield2']['type'];
$type2 = $_FILES['textfield3']['type']; 

if($type1 == 'image/gif' || $type1 == 'image/png' && $type2 == 'image/gif' || $type2  == 'image/png')
{
    echo 'Valid';
    echo $type1.'<br />'.$type2;
}
else
{
    echo 'Invalid';
}
```

If i select 1st file as a zip or any other format and then next as png it is going to valid that what i should not

Comment: Careful, in IE some of the 'filetypes' are completely different from that of FF. I couldn't figure out why my PNG files werent being displayed correctly, it seems they were uploaded as `image/x-png` type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP's [operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) makes && bind tighter than ||, so your test is coming out as:

```
if($type1 == 'image/gif' || ($type1 == 'image/png' && $type2 == 'image/gif') || $type2  == 'image/png')
                            ^----------------------------------------------^
```

Beyond that, do not use the user-provided `['type']` data for this. It's utterly trivial to forge, and someone can set to 'image/gif' while uploading nastyvirus.exe.

Comment: so is there any work around coz i have to validate three fields of images i can't even go through with 2 and i have 6 types of file formats to validate

Comment: use getimagesize(). It'll analyze the file itself and tell you what it is.

Comment: hi not hare image size validation , image upload validation as image uploading confirm.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
if(($type1 == 'image/gif' || $type1 == 'image/png') && 
   ($type2 == 'image/gif' || $type2  == 'image/png'))
        {
            echo 'Valid';

            echo $type1.'<br />'.$type2;
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'Invalid';
        }
```

This is due to operator precedence, which is documented here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Comment: Yup Niki That worked , fool of me just a simple thing and i am scratching my head from last 30min's  Special thanks to you coz u replied 1st and it was ryt

Answer (score 1):

This is due to [operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php). `&&` has higher precedence than `||` so your expression results in:

```
    $type1 == 'image/gif'
|| ($type1 == 'image/png' && $type2 == 'image/gif')
||  $type2 == 'image/png'
```

Use parentheses to make your intention clear:

```
   ($type1 == 'image/gif' || $type1 == 'image/png')
&& ($type2 == 'image/gif' || $type2 == 'image/png')
```

Additionally please note that the mime type is a client supplied data and thus is very easy to manipulate. Instead you should check for a valid GIF/PNG file header (using the [GD](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) library for example.)

Comment: Yup Niki That worked , fool of me just a simple thing and i am scratching my head from last 30min's